# Set the selected Jtree Node to JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtree

The function need to be accomplished is:

1. Select main group
2. Select from sub-group (TEST NAME)
3. Click >> button which means move the selection to Jtable
4. Show the slected (Test) with corresponding price on Jtable

conditions:

- if the selected node (test name) alread has been selected and added to the Jtable show message say: Test name already added.
- we can select and add many test name

[Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ZNC.jpg)

impotant to say that JTree data come from two tables main-group and sub-group

Here the code: of >> button

```
  try {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedElement = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) TestTree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        Object[] row = {selectedElement};
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) myTests_table.getModel();
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(row).toString() + "Hi");
        if (selectedElement.isLeaf() == true) {
            //model.addRow(row);
            // retrive date from DB price
            String sql = "SELECT  sub_group.name AS 'name', sub_group.price AS 'price'"
                    + "FROM sub_group \n"
                    + "where sub_group.name = '" + row + "' ";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                myTests_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Choose Test name!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
```

Dears
where is the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`TreeSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html) to your `JTree`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513). In the listener, update the `TableModel` of your `JTable`; the listening table will update itself accordingly, when your implementation of `setValueAt()` fires the relent `TableModelEvent`. Your table model should extend `AbstractTableModel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513), and contain a `Set<Row>`. Your `Row` class should hold the `name` and `price`. If `Row` implements `Comparable<Row>`, as shown in the example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781955/230513), then `Set<Row>` will automatically exclude duplicates when you invoke [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-).

Answer (score -1):

if the issue is that the new TableModel is not being reflected in the UI, use tableModel.fireTableDataChanged().

Comment: A `TableModelEvent` should be fired _only_ from within the scope of the `TableModel` itself, not externally.

Comment: could you point to any sources which say thats the best practice? there are other questions with same answers and they do say the same. ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data